# Using globs in GNU grep's path argument

Tags: grep, gnu, bsd, file-globs

BSD (Mac) grep allows for this command:

```
grep -n "FIXME" **/*.rb
```

But GNU grep forces me to specify at least a folder to start from:

```
grep -n "FIXME" {lib,spec}/**/*.rb
```

Is there a way to get this to behave like it does in BSD grep?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Switch to ack](http://beyondgrep.com/why-ack/). It uses the recursive strategy by default, and comes with loads of tricky regexes for types of language files available as flags.

For instance, writing:

```
ack FIXME --ruby
```

Will search the current directory recursively for anything that may be a Ruby file. This will work the same on Mac and Linux.